# tableview with custom table view cells disappear on scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I have a table view with custom tableview cells.
Each may have different heights.
Totally there are 14 rows but other rows are not visible and when i scroll up and down the rows are disappearing.

Please suggest where i am doing wrong. This is bugging me from 2 days. I am not able to find any solution.

Please find my code below for the tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="textarea")
    {
        return 100 ;
    }
    else if (fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="picklist")
    {
        return 60;
    }
    else if (fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="divider")
    {
        return 30;
    }
    else if (fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="scanner")
    {
        return 50;
    }
    else if (fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="multiselect")
    {
        return 60;
    }
    else if(fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType=="text")
    {
       var length =  fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementText?.characters.count
        if length! < 30
        {
            return 80;
        }else if length! < 60 && length! > 30  {
            return 110;
        }else if(length! < 100 && length! > 60)
        {
            return 130;
        }else if(length! < 150 && length! > 100 )
        {
        return 170;
        }
        else{
            return 140;
        }
    }else
   {
        return 200;

    }

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("No of elements Fetched===\(fetchedElements.count)")
    return fetchedElements.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


var variableType =  fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType
    if(variableType==nil)
    {
      variableType = "";
    }

var elementType = variableType!

    print("=============Element Type=\(elementType)==============")

   let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

    switch elementType {
    case "picklist":

        let dpcell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Textbox", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Textbox

        dpcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        dpcell.txtValue.layer.cornerRadius = 3


        dpcell.LabelName.text = "Country"//fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementText
        dpcell.txtValue.tag =  Int(fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementId)
        dpcell.txtValue.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GoToDropdown), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
        dpcell.txtValue.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        dpcell.txtValue.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        dpcell.txtValue.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        dpcell.LabelName.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        dpcell.LabelName.numberOfLines = 0
        dpcell.selectionStyle = .none
        print("============picklist==========\(indexPath.row)")
        return dpcell
    case "multiselect":
        let dpcell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Textbox", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Textbox

        dpcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        dpcell.txtValue.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        dpcell.LabelName.text = fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementText
        dpcell.txtValue.tag =  Int(fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementId)
        dpcell.txtValue.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GoToMultiSelect), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
        dpcell.txtValue.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        dpcell.txtValue.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left
        dpcell.txtValue.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        dpcell.txtValue.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        dpcell.selectionStyle = .none
         print("===========multiselect===========\(indexPath.row)")

        return dpcell

     default:
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "default"
         print("==========dummy cell============\(indexPath.row)")
        return cell

}
```

[image]

This happens after scroll down and up

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : I can't comment because i don't have enough reputation, so i could not ask you regarding certain queries i have.. But by reading your codes, this is what i can suggest.

I can see that your data  has quite a number of element types,for example, Picklist, divider, scanner and ect, in your heightForRow Delegate method..

However, in your cellForRow function, you have only two cases, PickList and MultiSelect... Thus, all the data types that have different element type, will return you a cell with a big "default" on it.

The only peculiar thing that i do not understand is that the tableview seems to have loaded perfectly in the first try. Thus, i was wondering on how you set up the tableview.

If you set it up in storyboard manually.. Then the first time, when the application loads, it will present whatever you have designed in your UITableView, but the moment you scroll up and down, the CellForItem method will kick in, and re-write the cell, returning you the big "default" cell you see on your list.

So if i am guessing it right..

Then what you have to do is simply adding all the type cases in your cellForRow methods's switch statement.

Comment: I just removed them to make the code appear a bit less in size. But i actually have them in my code. Still the same thing is happening. I tried changing the height for the default type, text type and all other types but nothing happens.  But you assumption is correct. I have setup the tableview using prototype cell.  Initially the code is loading only 10 rows out of 14 when i scroll down it is not able to create the other 4 rows . I see cellForRowAt indexPath is executing again on scroll but it is not creating the cells..

Comment: @NewbieIOS i see.. So, do you see a lot of "Dummy Cells" printed out in console when you scroll up and down?

Comment: I foresee that the problem may not lie with the switch statement .. So, it propagates up to the var variableType =  fetchedElements[indexPath.row].elementType
    if(variableType==nil)
    {
      variableType = "";
    }

Comment: You try to check the element types, see if they are the correct ones even after you scroll. You can test in UIScrollViewDidScroll Delegate Method (just an example) to see how the element type of your data is changing when you scroll up and down.

Comment: What i observed is, the tableview is initially loaded with with N number of rows...After that when i am scrolling down to get more rows then
 fetchedElements = try moc.fetch(elementFetch as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! [Element]
fetchedElements object is returning empty... So tableviewcells are not formed. How can i get rid of it?

Comment: @NewbieIOS I see.. then maybe the problem lies in the way you fetch your data... I think what you need to do now first is to try to fill in your tableViewData with some dummy data.. See if all tableViewCells are populated probably.. If they are, then pass in the real data again.. If the same error happens, then you can be sure the problem lies in your Fetching methods or the way you construct your tableData. Then you work your way around from there.

Comment: Can i send you my code file. I think you should be able to find the issue..?

Comment: @NewbieIOS i can't help you with that.. I understand your frustration with the current code.. But you can only help yourself.. It will simply take too much time for anyone else to understand your code.

Comment: thats ok. Thank you. I am trying different approaches. I hope something will work out. But thanks again for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into dispatch async & tableView.reloadData

Since I cannot see all of your code, I would suggest that you create a function that will be called inside viewDidLoad. Inside this function, of course include the lines below, as well as whatever you want inside of your tableView cells. I'm assuming you're using an array for your tableViews data

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 

tableView.reloadData

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Will i not lose all data that is existing on textbox etc if i do tableView.reloadData?

Comment: @NewbieiOS This simply refreshes the tableViews cells. An issue with tableView cells is that even if the data is there, it will either load other data sometimes, before actually showing it in the tableView. Calling dispatch async and reload data will prevent this, making it show a lot quicker, if not instantly. Hope this helps

Comment: Where should i use the above statement?

Comment: @NewbieIOS 

func reloadTableView (
DispatchQueue.main.async {
tableView.reloadData
}

then call reloadTableView() inside your viewDidLoad

Comment: If i use this it is just reloading the empty rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129749/discussion-between-newbieios-and-daniel-dramond).